# Containerless deployment of JAX-RS Restful Service In Java

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, jetty, jax-rs

JAX-RS is a specification that helps you develop restful web services in Java.
But JAX-RS seem to be requiring a servlet container like "Tomcat"or "Jetty".

Managing container in a clustered mode is painful and more operations heavy. 
Is there way to start JAX-RS service like a normal Java program/application ?

I want to use JAX-RS implementation but I don't want to follow typical"deploy" cycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JAX-RS is strongly linked to HTTP, hence most implementations (eg Jersey, Apache CXF) run in a servlet, which in turn runs in a container such as Tomcat or Jetty. I guess you could develop your own standalone JAX-RS implementation, but you'd end up reinventing the wheel as you'd be forced to implement most aspects of a web server.

Your worries about clustering also seem unfounded. Clustering Tomcat is simple, it is a very common thing to do and there's [plenty of information available on the subject](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cluster-howto.html). It seems like clustering a custom implementation would actually be a much harder job.

Comment: In addition, the REST interfaces should be stateless. So clustering should not be a problem at all.

Comment: Jersey can also run with the JDK mini webserver.